# carouFredSel Duplicating Pagination Bullets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination, caroufredsel

I'm setting up a simple carouFredSel and I'm getting a weird effect.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="list_carousel responsive banners">
    <ul id="foo2">
        <li><a href="#"> <img src="1.jpg"></li>
        <li><a href="#"> <img src="2.jpg"></li>
        <li><a href="#"> <img src="3.jpg"></li>
        <li><a href="#"> <img src="4.jpg"></li>
        <li><a href="#"> <img src="5.jpg"></li>
        <li><a href="#"> <img src="6.jpg"></li>
        <li><a href="#"> <img src="7.jpg"></li>
        <li><a href="#"> <img src="8.jpg"></li>
        <li><a href="#"> <img src="9.jpg"></li>
        <li><a href="#"> <img src="10.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <a id="prev-banner" class="prev" href="#">&lt;</a>
    <a id="next-banner" class="next" href="#">&gt;</a>
    <div id="pager-banner"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#foo2").carouFredSel({
            align: 'left',
            responsive: true,
            width: 690,
            height: 198,
            items: {
                start: -1,
                visible: 1,
                width: 690,
                height: 198
            },
            scroll: {
                items: 1,
                duration: 1000,
                fx: 'crossfade'
            },
            auto: true,
            swipe: {
                onTouch     : true,
                onMouse     : true
            },
            prev: {
                button: "#prev-banner",
                key: "left"
            },
            next: {
                button: "#next-banner",
                key: "right"
            },
            pagination  : {
                container       : "#pager-banner",
                anchorBuilder   : function( nr ) {
                    return "<a href='#'><i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i></a>";
                }
            }
        });
```

I have no idea how this is happening, but when I run this, the number of pagination bullets are doubling. Where I should have TEN (10), I now have TWENTY (20).

I do have other carouFredSels on the page, but I removed them prior to posting this question to see if MAYBE somehow the streams of code where getting crossed, but that is not the issue.  When this carousel is on the page all by itself, the number of bullets are being duplicated.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hrm. Could you make a jsfiddle or something similar for this? I'd like to help, but I'm having trouble replicating the issue.

Comment: the code you see above was all I had on my page, I don't know how much more a jfiddle would help.

Comment: So nothing other than jQuery (1 or 2?) and carouFredSel? No CSS other than Font Awesome's? I'll try again to replicate tomorrow.

Comment: I actually found the issue was SOMETHING in my syntax.  I'm trying to pinpoint WHAT that error was, but I started over, and I am no longer getting the error.

Comment: Oh good! I was running out of things to try to replicate it. :-D

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#foo2').carouFredSel({
    items: 1,
    responsive: true,
    direction: "left",
    scroll: {
        items: 1,
        easing: "elastic",
        duration: 500,
        pauseOnHover: true
    },
    items: {
        visible: {
            min: 1,
            max: 1,
        }
    },
    prev: '#prev-banner',
    next: '#next-banner',
    pagination: {
        container: '.sliderpager',
        anchorBuilder: false // remove default rendering
    }
});
```

Comment: Edit your post to add code formatting. Also, consider adding any explanation to your code.